# Pandas: Reshape wide dataframe to multi-indexed long

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of ratings of photographs, generated by many individual raters.
Each rater is given several images to rate, and for each image, a rater provides several different ratings, plus a description.

So, for example, a rater might be asked to rate 3 different photos, and provide separate ratings on a 0-5 scale for how happy, sad, and interesting each photo is.  In addition, a rater is asked to provide a short text description of each photo.

The same photograph may be rated by multiple raters, but not all photographs will have been rated by the same number of raters.

Currently my data are in this form (each url represents a photo):

```
rater_id | url1 | url2 | url3 | rating_1(1) | rating_2(1) | rating_1(2) | rating_2(2)   | rating_1(3) | rating_2(3) | description(1) | description(2) | description(3)
     001 |   a  |   b  |   c  |     3.0     |     2.5     |     4.0     |     1.5       |     5.0     |     5.0     |  sunny day     |  rainy day     |  foggy day
     002 |   a  |   b  |   d  |     1.0     |     4.5     |     3.0     |     3.5       |     1.0     |     3.5     |  sunshine      |  rain          |  snow
```

I have a few transformations I'm trying to achieve here.
First I want to change the data frame so that it is indexed by photo url - with all of the url fields (url1, url2, etc) melted into one long column `url`. Meaning:

```
url1 | url2 | url3
-----|------|-----
  a  |   b  |  c
```

becomes

```
url
---
 a
 b
 c
```

Within each `url` index, there is a nested index for `rater_id`, which then has a row of that rater's ratings and description for the given photo.
Eg.:

```
                | rating_1 | rating_2 | description
url | rater_id
 a  |      001  |    3.0   |   2.5    |  sunny day
    |      002  |    1.0   |   4.5    |  sunshine
----|-----------|----------|----------|------------
 b  |      001  |    4.0   |   1.5    |  rainy day
    |      002  |    4.5   |   3.0    |  rain
----|-----------|----------|----------|------------
 c  |      001  |    5.0   |   5.0    |  foggy day
----|-----------|----------|----------|------------
 d  |      002  |    1.0   |   3.5    |  snow
```

Finally, I want to aggregate ratings and descriptions for each photo url:
- mean and variance of numeric ratings
- tab-separated string of all descriptions
- number of raters who have rated each photo

Eg.:

```
url | rating_1_avg | rating_1_var | rating_2_avg | rating_2_var | all_descriptions      | total_ratings 
 a  |     2.0      |     2.0      |     3.0      |     2.0      | sunny day    sunshine |      2
----|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-----------------------|--------------
 b  |     4.25     |     0.125    |     2.25     |     1.125    | rainy day    rain     |      2
----|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-----------------------|--------------
 c  |     5.0      |     NA       |     5.0      |     NA       | foggy day             |      1
----|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-----------------------|--------------
 d  |     1.0      |     NA       |     3.5      |     NA       | snow                  |      1
```

I've tried a number of approaches with the [Pandas reshaping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/reshaping.html) tools, including `melt` and `wide_to_long`, but I can't figure out how to first get the photo urls into long format, and then created a nested index to arrange the data as I've presented above.  I'm pretty comfortable with Pandas `groupby` and basic aggregation, but this is a bit beyond my skill level.  Any help is much appreciated!

Note: The fields I've given in these dummy data are not the exact names as in the actual dataset, but they follow the same naming conventions exactly.  The photo urls are all `url1`, `url2`, etc, and the ratings fields are denoted as `rating_<rating_category_number>(<url_number>)`, eg. `rating_1(2)`. The description fields are denoted as `description(<url_number>)`, eg. `description(2)`.

Here's Python code to build the initial dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '001', 1: '002'},
                   'url1': {0: 'a', 1: 'a'},
                   'url2': {0: 'b', 1: 'b'},
                   'url3': {0: 'c', 1: 'd'}})

df['rating_1(1)'] = [3.0, 1]
df['rating_2(1)'] = [2.5, 4.5]
df['rating_1(2)'] = [4.0, 3]
df['rating_2(2)'] = [1.5, 3.5]
df['rating_1(3)'] = [5.0, 1]
df['rating_2(3)'] = [5.0, 3.5]
df['description(1)'] = ['sunny day','sunshine']
df['description(2)'] = ['rainy day','rain']
df['description(3)'] = ['foggy day','snow']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first find columns for each category by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and then use not well known `pd.lreshape`. Last aggregate columns by [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html), [`var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.var.html), [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) and `join`:

```
#select columns with each category
rat1 = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'rating_1')].tolist()
print rat1
['rating_1(1)', 'rating_1(2)', 'rating_1(3)']

rat2 = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'rating_2')].tolist()
url = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'url')].tolist()
desc = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'description')].tolist()

df =  pd.lreshape(df, {'rat1': rat1, 'rat2': rat2,'url': url,'desc': desc})
print df
  rater_id url  rat2  rat1       desc
0    '001'   a   2.5   3.0  sunny day
1    '002'   a   4.5   1.0   sunshine
2    '001'   b   1.5   4.0  rainy day
3    '002'   b   3.5   3.0       rain
4    '001'   c   5.0   5.0  foggy day
5    '002'   d   3.5   1.0       snow

#aggregate
df = df.groupby(['url']).agg({'rat1':['mean', 'var'],
                              'rat2':['mean', 'var'], 
                              'desc': ' '.join, 
                              'rater_id': 'count'})

#reset multiindex in columns
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]
```

```
print df
     rater_id_count  rat2_mean  rat2_var  rat1_mean  rat1_var  \
url                                                             
a                 2        3.5       2.0        2.0       2.0   
b                 2        2.5       2.0        3.5       0.5   
c                 1        5.0       NaN        5.0       NaN   
d                 1        3.5       NaN        1.0       NaN   

              desc_join  
url                      
a    sunny day sunshine  
b        rainy day rain  
c             foggy day  
d                  snow
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  Great find on `lreshape`.  I was a bit surprised that the [`lreshape` source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L799) describes the function as "Reshape long-format data to wide", seems like it's actually going from wide to long.  In any case you solved my problem, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: If you want you can upvote too. Click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following

```
ids_url1 = ['id', 'rating_1(1)', 'rating_2(1)', 'rating_3(1)', 'description(1)']
ids_url2 = ['id', 'rating_1(2)', 'rating_2(2)', 'rating_3(2)', 'description(2)']
ids_url3 = ['id', 'rating_1(3)', 'rating_2(3)', 'rating_3(3)', 'description(3)']

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=ids_url1, value_vars=['url1'])
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=ids_url2, value_vars=['url2'])
df3 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=ids_url3, value_vars=['url3'])
df1.drop(axis=1, labels='variable', inplace=True)
df1.set_index(['value', 'id'], inplace=True)
df1.columns = ["rating_1", "rating_2", "rating_3", "description"]
df2.drop(axis=1, labels='variable', inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['value', 'id'], inplace=True)
df2.columns = ["rating_1", "rating_2", "rating_3", "description"]
df3.drop(axis=1, labels='variable', inplace=True)
df3.set_index(['value', 'id'], inplace=True)
df3.columns = ["rating_1", "rating_2", "rating_3", "description"]

dfn = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=0)
```

And then you can just do `groupby`'s as desired and concatenate the results

```
dfn.groupby(axis=0, level=0).mean()

       rating_1  rating_2  rating_3
value
a           2.0       3.5       NaN
b           3.5       2.5       NaN
c           5.0       5.0       NaN
d           1.0       3.5       NaN

dfn.groupby(axis=0, level=0)['description'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))

value
a    sunny day sunshine
b        rainy day rain
c             foggy day
d                  snow
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I can see how it would work reasonably well with the small example data I created, but it wasn't quite as compact or scalable as the other offered solution.  (Or, at least, I couldn't get your solution to work as well as the other one.)  Much appreciated though!